# Om mercedes 364 turbo diesel fuel line question

Tags: diesel, mercedes-benz

Hello I'm busy with a conversion on a om 364 Turbo mercedes Benz diesel engine. I am battling to find a diagram for the fuel lines and which is the push and return fuel lines on this motor and where they must be connected to. I have checked the manuals, YouTube videos and pictures but nothing gives me info on this.

Please can someone shed some light on this for me. I will greatly appreciate this as this is the only aspect that we are stuck in.

Thank you